# What does '%'%'%' mean and why is it equal to 0?

Tags: c, char, modulo

The following program:

```
int main()
{
    printf("%d", '%'%'%');
    return 0;
}
```

Produces the output:

```
0
```

I would like to know what is the reason for this.

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Do you know what the `%` operator does?

Comment: What do you think the remainder will be after dividing 37 by 37? Because that's what you're printing.

Comment: thanks Adrian, i just didn't see that we make operation between the chars

Comment: The -4 rate for this question it is imho too harsh. I've seen spamming question with a bigger rate. Now, it is not the deeper and time-saving question of the world (from the perspective of a developer searching solutions on SO) but it is clear and tricky at the same time (it stole me a smile).

Comment: @omEchan Incidentally, was your choice of the `%` character in any way related to the use of that character in `printf` format specifiers? (This should have been asked *long* before any answer was posted!!)

Comment: `'%'` is an `int` (exactly like `72` in all respects, except, maybe the value)

Answer (score 7):

The second parameter to `printf`:

```
'%'%'%'
```

More easily read as:

```
'%' % '%'
```

Is applying the modulus operator `%` to the characters `'%'` and `'%'`.  Because characters are encoded as integer values, this is the same as getting the remainder of dividing a number by itself.

Dividing a non-zero number (a printable character cannot have code 0) by itself will always result in a remainder of 0, which is what is being printed.

Comment: thanks..i didn't figure out that we make operation between two chars, now everything is clear!

Comment: @omEchan you can use the `%` operator on the `char` type, because it is an integer type. But, such *characters* are not `char` type, they are `int` type anyway, and this is a common misconception that a character must be a `char`.

Comment: Characters are *encoded* as 8-bit values (if ASCII is used). Character *constants* have the `int` type in C. Subtle difference.

Comment: @AdrianMole: If you want to be precise about it, characters are encoded as `CHAR_BIT` values. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The expression prints the remainder of the division of `'%'` by `'%'` which is 0. That is the value being printed through `"%d"` specifier of `printf`.

Characters are encoded as 8-bit values (in [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) as an example), character constants, in reallity, have `int` type in C.

In this case `'%'` is 37, you are printing the remainder of the division of 37 by 37.

Having `'%'%'%'` is the equivalent of having `37%37`.

Comment: i know what modulo is..my problem was in understanding of the confusing syntax

Comment: @omEchan, characters have a numerical representation, in this case `'%'` in ASCII is 37, so if you divide 37 by 37, the rest is 0.

Comment: @AdrianMole: On the other hand, I do not expect this knowledge is discoverable from this question. Stack Overflow accumulates a great many questions and answers that are not easily searchable. So the question and answer might provide little value, but that is because they are not discoverable, not because the knowledge is not actually valuable. I would like to see Stack Overflow either redirect or organize elementary questions and find some way to concentrate on things less easily answered elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

`'%'%'%'` is a purposely obfuscated expression that evaluates to `0` because it is the remainder of the division of `'%'` by itself.

`'%'` is a *character constant* which in C is an integer with type `int` and an implementation defined value (`37` in the ASCII character set used on the vast majority of current systems). Since this value cannot be `0`, dividing it by itself evaluates to `1` with a remainder of `0`, hence the code prints `0`.

Note however that for full portability, the program should end its output with a newline and the `printf` function should be declared with the proper prototype by including `<stdio.h>`.

Here is a modified version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", '%'%'%');
    return 0;
}
```

Here are some variations on the same idea:

- `'-'-'-'`, `'^'^'^'`, `'<'<'<'`, `'>'>'>'` all evaluate to `0`.
- `'/'/'/'` and `'='=='='` evaluate to `1`.
- `'&'&'&'&&'&'&'&'` and `'|'|'|'||'|'|'|'` both evaluate to `1`.